# Titan DB 0.5.4 (titan-0.5.4-hadoop2) , Exception after importing/load data using loadGraphSON()

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm using Titan DB (titan-0.5.4-hadoop2) over cassandra.

Trying to export/import data with JSON format.

The save action occurs successfully, but after loadGraphSON() command, I get an Exception.

The code:

```
g = TitanFactory.open('../conf/titan-db.properties')
titangraph[cassandra:[localhost]]
g.saveGraphSON('../Test1233.json')
g.commit()
g.loadGraphSON('../Test1233.json')
```

The stack trace:

```
Not a single key: roles. Use addProperty instead
Display stack trace? [yN]
Not a single key: roles. Use addProperty instead
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not a single key: roles. Use addProperty instead
  at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.setProperty(StandardTitanTx.java:755)
  at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.setProperty(AbstractVertex.java:244)
  at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.setProperty(AbstractVertex.java:239)
  at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.wrappers.batch.BatchGraph$BatchVertex.setProperty(BatchGraph.java:492)
  at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.io.graphson.GraphSONUtility.vertexFromJson(GraphSONUtility.java:136)
  at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.io.graphson.GraphSONReader.inputGraph(GraphSONReader.java:158)
  at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.io.graphson.GraphSONReader.inputGraph(GraphSONReader.java:104)
  at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.io.graphson.GraphSONReader.inputGraph(GraphSONReader.java:88)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
  at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.loaders.GraphLoader$_load_closure14.doCall(GraphLoader.groovy:126)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:84)
  at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
  at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:67)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:152)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66)
  at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:78)
  at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:91)
  at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.main(Console.java:95)
gremlin>
```

Comment: So you export from and import to the same graph? I assume this would cause all unique constraints you put into your schema to be violated. Do you have the same error when importing into an empty Titan keyspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a vertex property defined in your Titan schema with Cardinality SET or LIST. When you have a collection property instead of a SINGLE property, `addProperty()` is what needs to be used. This is the error you're seeing.

As Matthias described in this [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/FtLIZFVUHBM/Gk73jUL9zWoJ), the GraphSON utilities provided by Blueprints 2.5.0 does not support Titan's extended schema model. The `loadGraphSON()` Gremlin step you're calling on uses `BatchGraph` under the covers, as you can see in your stack trace. This is likely fixed in the latest Titan release 1.0, so you should consider upgrading.